# Display python matplotlib pyplot using html without saving figure

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I have the figure X.graph which is a matplotlib.figure.Figure being passed to an html template using render_template('page', graph= X.graph) from Flask.  Is it possible to have my html page display this figure without saving it as an image and accessing it that way?